# Inserting data from txt file into database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I want to insert the data from the txt file into the database table. Until this point, I am used to doing this with simple text files such as data only separated by `,` or `#` etc. But the tricky part here is that the text file looks like this:

```
    +--------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
    !         Settlement Category          ! Transaction Amount ! Reconciliation Amnt !          Fee Amount !  Transaction Amount ! Reconciliation Amnt !          Fee Amount !   Count !           Net Value !
    !                                      !             Credit !              Credit !              Credit !               Debit !               Debit !               Debit !   Total !                     !
    +--------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+

    ! MC Acq Fin Detail ATM Out                           5.00                   3.57                 49.75                  0.00                  0.00                  0.00        31                  3.32 !
    ! MC Acq Fin Detail Retail Out                        5.40                 262.01                  0.00                  0.00                  0.00                 -3.96        10                258.05 !

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      Totals :                           10.40                 265.58                 49.75                  0.00                  0.00                 -3.96        41                261.37
```

So my question is which approach should I take here. I just need a recommendation, not the code

Comment: what is tricky about it? read the file, store the data in memory, write it to your db

Comment: I do not know how to separate column names and data here in this particular structure.  for example, column names are in two lines

Comment: yes, but you know up front how many lines they are on. or just understand that the data begins after the second ------------------- line

Comment: I see the point now,  your comment gave me an idea thank you @Stultuske!